# Is every measurable function in a Borel sigma algebra defined only on open sets?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets, borel-measures

Maybe this question is rather trivial.

Suppose that there exists a Borel measurable function $f: {\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. Does this imply that $f$ is measurable only for inputs of the form $(a,b)$ or a collection of inputs of this form? My main question is  it enough to focus on inputs of the form of open ntervals without neglecting other sets for which $f$ is measurable?

Comment: Is $R$ the set of real numbers?

Comment: @Quantic_Solver Yes sorry I edited it

Comment: What do you mean by "f^{-1} is defined"? There are no definitions here. Maybe you mean that $f^{-1}\{0, 1\}$ **is** a open set or a union of open sets.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Yes you are right. I guess what I am really asking whether $f$ is measurable only in open intervals. I want to be able to focus only on inputs of the form $(a,b)$ and be sure that there exists no other set of some form for which $f$ is also measurable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of $f$ being Borel measurable, $f^{-1}(\{0,1\})\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

And the Borel set $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ contains all the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I see so do you think it would be safe to say that $f$ is defined only in open intervals of the form $f((a,b))$? or a collection of them of course?

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Comment: Thank you so much!